# Render tree component in React

Tags: reactjs, tree

We have a tree object of this type.

```
 {
  name: '0222',
  type: '0333',
  child: {
    name: '0555',
    type: '0666',
    child: {
        name: '0235',
        type: '0654',
        child: [] 
          }
      }
}
```

How to display hierarchical nesting in a react. For example

```
<div>
     <p> 0222 </p> 
     <div> 
           <p> 0555 </p> 
                       <div> <p>0235</p>
                       </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively render the component by traversing over your data like below

```js
let data = {
  name: '0222',
  type: '0333',
  child: {
    name: '0555',
    type: '0666',
    child: {
        name: '0235',
        type: '0654',
        child: [] 
          }
      }
}
const Comp = ({data}) => {
   return (  
      <div>
        <p>{data.name}</p>
        {data.child && <Comp data={data.child} />}
     </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Comp data={data} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```